# Не получается открыть скриптом изображение в фотошопе

Tags: javascript, photoshop, jsx

Никак не могу понять, как открыть картинку с помощью скрипта в фотошопе.
Использую такой код

```
var f = new File("D:/images/img01231.jpg");
f.open( "r" );
```

И ничего, никакой ошибки, ничего не открывает.
Подскажите, в чем собственно дело?

Comment: А путь точно не `D:\\images\\img01231.jpg`?

Comment: @VladimirGonchar что я только не перепробовал, ничего не берет

Answer (score 0):

Помог этот вариант:

```
// Set the ruler units to pixels
var originalRulerUnits = app.preferences.rulerUnits
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS
var fileRef = new File( "D:\\images\\img01231.jpg" );
// Get a reference to the file that we want to open

// open the file
app.open( fileRef );

// restore unit settings
app.preferences.rulerUnits = originalRulerUnits
```